# Error in Anndata conversion: module 'rpy2.robjects.conversion' has no attribute 'get_conversion'

Tags: python, r

I am trying to run the single cell best practice tutorial https://www.sc-best-practices.org/preprocessing_visualization/quality_control.html, but I have a problem in converting between AnnData and SingleCellExperiment.

```
import anndata2ri
import logging

import rpy2.rinterface_lib.callbacks as rcb
import rpy2.robjects as ro

rcb.logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
ro.pandas2ri.activate()
anndata2ri.activate()

%load_ext rpy2.ipython
```

the code is running but this line is not working `anndata2ri.activate()`  it give me this error

AttributeError: module 'rpy2.robjects.conversion' has no attribute 'get_conversion'

I tried to change rpy2 version `!pip install rpy2==3.5.2` or `!pip install rpy2==3.5.7` and reload but it is not working as well, anyone know how to fix it?